# What is the difference between the span and the i markups in HTML

Tags: html, markup

This is what the Mozilla documentation say about the i markup :

> The HTML Idiomatic Text element (i) represents a range of text that
> is set off from the normal text for some reason, such as idiomatic
> text, technical terms, taxonomical designations, among others.

And about the span markup :

> The HTML span element is a generic inline container for phrasing
> content, which does not inherently represent anything.

What I understand is both are for differentiating bits of text inside larger paragraph. What am I missing ?

Comment: did you try to google "span vs i"?

Comment: Yes I did, all the results are comparisons between div and span

Comment: If you ask practically, there is no difference. If you want something technical, check w3c specs.  `b`, `i`, `em` have no semantic difference, i.e no screen reader differentiate those elements. So it's either visual or nothing.

Answer (score 2):

There are theoretical differences, but there's one massive practical difference.  The i markup means the contained text displays in italics in the browser, span does nothing on its own except, as you say, 'differentiate bits of text':

```html
<p>With &lt;i&gt;:  <i>Hello World</i></p>
<p>With &lt;span&gt;: <span>Hello World</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` has a meaning, `span` doesn't. A `span` merely allows you to put a span of text into its own separate container element. By default that means nothing, but *you* can ascribe any meaning to it you want. Typically you'd give that `span` a `class` and apply some specific style to that class.

`i`'s existing meaning you have described in your post. Screen readers for example might apply a different emphasis to *idiomatic* expressions than for standard text, and it's already styled *italic* by default.

Comment: There is no screen-reader applying any significance to `i`, `em` and `b`. That's even said somewhere in Mozilla Docs. Most ppl saying that never used a SR.

Comment: Fair enough, it was an example what a *semantic* meaning implies and how it *might* be used. I have little personal experience with screen readers, so that was more or less made up.

Answer (score 1):

In html there is a paradigm of semantics of html tags (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/semantic-html5-elements/).
`span` is a general container without any meaning for text blocks. The same as `div` for blocks.
But `i` has a semantic meaning.

Comment: Could you please make the question part more clear and also if you can make sure that you google it before hand and if the answers you find isn't sufficient, you can mention them here and mention your problem with them.

Answer (score 1):

`span` is a generic container. It is more like `div`. But `div` is a block-level container where `span` is an inline container.

Use the `<i>` element only when there is not a more appropriate semantic element, such as:

```
<em> (emphasized text)
<strong> (important text)
<mark> (marked/highlighted text)
<cite> (the title of a work)
<dfn> (a definition term)
```

Please see the [reference1](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_i.asp) or [referance2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i).

Comment: What you call "reference" is not a very solid source of wisdom. Link the w3c.org if you think it's worth